# Server add addslashes() itself. How can I stop this?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I use `addslashes()` for insert data. But server also add `addslashes()` itself.

For example:

```
$str="jogindersinh's company";
$q="insert into company(company_nm)values(addslashes($str))";
```

string must insert in database like `jogindersinh's company`.

But data insert in database like `jogindersinh\'s company`, because of add `addslashes()` second time.

So when I fetch data. Get result `jogindersinh\'s company`.

So how can I stop server to add `addslashes()`?

Comment: Do you have magic quotes enabled? What does `var_dump(get_magic_quotes_gpc());` output?

Comment: `addslashes` should not be in your code. **DO NOT USE IT**. You need to do [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). As a note, "Magic Quotes", which usually causes this problem, was considered such a bad idea it was removed in PHP 5.4.

Comment: Or better yet, use prepared queries and pass variables as parameters, then you don't have to worry about doing escaping at all.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like [Magic Quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) is enabled. You should turn that off.

Apart from that, `addslashes()` is not going to protect you from sql injection. You should use prepared statements instead (or the dedicated escaping functions like `mysql_real_escape_string()` if you must).

Answer (score 0):

Look into your php settings file and disable Magic Quotes. Also protect your query's against sql-injections. Try to validate the input using Ctype_ and use Mysql_real_escape_string().